# DriveApp File.makeCopy() not copying document body

Tags: google-apps-script

Using the following syntax for Google DriveApp:

```
var folderVar= DriveApp.getFolderById(corporateFolderId);
var fileVar= DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
fileVar.makeCopy(title, folderVar);
fileVar.setTrashed(true);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to copy the recently generated file from my logged-in user drive to a folder on my corporate account that I have permissions to. I then trash the document from my logged-in user drive. This is in fact performing the copy, and the title is correct, but the document body is empty. I am performing this after document creation, so order of operations is fine. Logging shows that the same document file ID that is in my logged-in user account (but trashed) is the one being copied, but the new document in the corporate folder is blank.

Any tips are greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: HI Justin, i've tested this and for me it works like a charm so a couple of questions: Do you have editor permissions on the source document/folder? Is there content in the source document? What kind of document are you copying?

Comment: Yes, I have full permissions to the source file structure. The source document does have content (usually 20+ pages), and is a report document with a lot of text and graphs/charts.

Comment: It's important to note that before the recent update that sunset some API calls, I was using DocsList calls to do the same thing (except I was indicating the source folder right away for saving into, which it allowed you to do). DriveApp requires using your logged-in root account for the document creation, then you copy it over.

Comment: Allright i think this is what's happening:
You are trashing the file while its copying the data into the new document. Could you try and remove the setTrashed?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I did think of that prior and commended out the setTrashed() call, but it didn't change the outcome. The copy is creating a fully new file with a new ID, so I don't think calling setTrashed() on the original file, after copy, will affect the copied file since it's a different file ID.

Comment: Hi Justin, could you check if this behaviour happens on all documents or only some documents? If it happens on all could you post or share with me the complete code of your script?

Answer (score 0):

You said you're performing the script after Document Creation, do you are also saving it?.

Comment: You should add a link to the saveAndClose() DocumentApp documentation

Comment: The copy is occurring right after all method calls to populate it with content, before the scripts do any wrap-up. Shouldn't it simply copy the document in whatever state it's in at the time of makeCopy() being called?